# compare two Groovy dates

Tags: grails, date, groovy, compare

I take two dates from the user.

```
<g:datePicker name="now"/>  <g:datePicker name="early"/>
```

Then, in my controller:

```
if((params.early).compareTo(params.now)==0) {
  early=new Date(1970,1,1)
}
else {
  //do something
}
```

the else part is getting executed even if the date is same.
how do we compare date in groovy?

Comment: if(params.ear==params.now)
   {
    ear=new Date(0160,0,1)//make date for the start day of project release
    log.info(ear)
    now=params.now
   }
   else
   {
    ear=params.ear
    now=params.now
   }

Comment: this is working just the question is how the year is being interpretted. 0160 is 2011 according to log results .how ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you get if you print out `params.early` and `params.now`?  Are you sure they are not Strings?  If they are dates do they have a time component -- this might be the reason for them not being equal.

You should just be able to do:

```
if( params.early == params.now ) {
  early = Date.parse( "yyyy/MM/dd", "1970/01/01" )
}
else {
  // do something
}
```

Or, if they are Dates with a time component, (and you are just interested in the date):

```
if( params.early.clearTime() == params.now.clearTime() ) {
  early = Date.parse( "yyyy/MM/dd", "1970/01/01" )
}
else {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I have used <g:datePicker name="early"/> I have used <g:datePicker name="now"/>  to get date from user

Comment: Right, so they should be Dates.  When you print them out, are you sure they're the same?

Comment: yeah they are exactly same with time appended at the end

Comment: @user1211304 If they are with times, can you try the `clearTime` method I showed in the second part of my answer?

Comment: actually u cud even set the seconds in the datePicker

Comment: @user1211304 Then I assume they are different?  If you only want to set the day, try adding `precision="day"` to [your datepicker](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/datePicker.html)...

Comment: i tried that. its not going to else even then, although dates are same

Comment: and parse is not taken as function i suppose, its striked out in the code

Comment: @user1211304 _"...its not going to else even then..."_ If they are the same, why would it go to the else?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that `(params.early).compareTo` part is correct.

Anyway, why not to use `equals` instead of `compareTo == 0`? I mean:

```
if (params.early == params.now) {
   //....
} else {
   //....
}
```

Comment: even that isn't working. I tried this same code at first. and time is same in both.

Comment: Can you show actual values for `params.early` and `params.now`?

Comment: the if part isnt getting executed it automatically comes to else even though the dates are same

Comment: Can you show actual values for params.early and params.now?        yes. its with time also

Answer (score 0):

I would use the date type coersion to ensure you are getting dates:

```
params.date( 'early' ).compareTo( params.date( 'now' ) ) == 0
```